# angular 2 table pagination

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to make a paginated table, I send a request to an api but it only returns 10 rows and I get the total row count from header.
Starting from this point I want to paginate my table in 10 rows, thus let's suppose this:

[image: resources]

> 5 rows = 1 button on table (or disabled)
>
> 14 rows = 2 buttons on table
>
> 40 rows = 4 buttons on table
>
> 56 rows = 6 buttons and so forth

So, on every numbered button I want to send a parameter to my API indicating the number of page that will be the same that the number of button but, as you can see, I'm unable see at least one second button

this is my view:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
     <th><span class="name">ResourceId</span></th>
     <th><span class="name">Parent Resource Set</span></th>
     <th><span class="name">Name</span></th>
     <th><span class="name">Description</span></th>
     <th><span class="name">Route</span></th>
     <th><span class="name">Environment</span></th>
  </tr>
  <tbody #tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let resource of resources| paginate: {itemsPerPage:10, currentPage:page, id: '1'}; let i = index">
       <td>{{ resource.resourceId }}</td>
       <td>{{ resource.resourceSetId }}</td>
       <td>{{ resource.name }}</td>
       <td>{{ resource.description }}</td>
       <td>{{ resource.route }}</td>
       <td>{{ resource.environment }}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   <footer>total row count {{head}}</footer>
  </table>
 <pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event" id="1" maxSize="10" directionLinks="true" autoHide="false"></pagination-controls>
```

my component:

```
export class ResourcesComponent implements OnInit {
  resources : Resources[];
   data;
   head;
 constructor(private router: Router, private resourcesv: ResourcesService) { }
   getResources() {
      this.resourcesv.getResources().subscribe(resources => this.resources =resources);
   }
   ngOnInit() {
        this.getResources();
        this.resourcesv.fetchdata().subscribe((data)=>{ this.data = data.json,
        this.head = data.headers.get('x-rowcount');
      return this.head;
   });
  }
 }
```

and my service :

```
 @Injectable()
 export class ResourcesService {
  private resourcesurl = "http://localhost:9111/v1/resources";
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getResources() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("api_key", "123456");
    return this.http.get(this.resourcesurl, { headers: headers }).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
   }
   fetchdata() {
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append("api_key", "123456");
   return this.http.get(this.resourcesurl, { headers: headers })
  .map((res) => res)
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
   let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
  }
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
     const body = error.json() || '';
     const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
     errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
  }  else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
   }
   console.error(errMsg);
   return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
 }
```

I want to set a certain amount of buttons according to the number of records that are returned in the custom header

any idea?